# How to Allow access Only to "non-logged in" user in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I understand I can restrict page access to logged in users only by using the `AuthorizeAttribute [Authorize]` in .NET Core.

However, I want to allow access to one page only when authorized users are logged out. Because this page is for people outside the company, and I need to prevent an employee from forgetting logging out of the system before handing the laptop over to the outside person to view the page. Is there any easy way like `[not Authorize]` to do this?

I understand I can force a logout in that page or check authentication information. I am just wondering if there is a really easy way to do this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [AllowAnnonymous] helps you how much but you can try creating a custom filter which will check if the user is logged in or not
based on that you can create a view page which will let the AuthenticatedUser know that session is active and needs to logout to see the page content

```
public class NotLogInAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("SomePage", "Shared", null);
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can decorate your method with [NotLogInAttribute] attribute